# Set CreatedById field to another user in Flow builder when a Record is created

Tags: visual-workflow

I have created a flow builder that creates a record when a button is clicked.
The only problem is that when the record is created, I need the CreatedById field to be set with a username different to the person who creates the record.
Basically the flow is used to create a record on behalf of another user.

[image]

I have tried to use assignement to assign a userId different to the person who creates the record but can't make it work

[image]

Could someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Created By is not an editable field. It can only be modified on create through API tooling if the ["Create Audit Fields"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&type=1&mode=1) feature is enabled, but I don't believe that will work for flows. It would only work if you were creating records with something like Dataloader.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to my question...
Basically, I needed to create a invocable method and add the Apex class in my flow via the Action Element...
now it works

Comment: How does this overwrite the `CreatedById`? Does the invocable run in a separated context or are you leveraging the ["Create Audit Fields"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000334139&type=1&mode=1) permission in your code?

Comment: Basically in my Apex class when inserting the record. I match the createdbyId with the other record. for exemple 
for(Case c : caseList) {
            ideaList.add(new Idea(createdById = c.CreatedById, Title = c.Subject, CommunityId = community.Id));
        }
then when my flow creates the record, it set the createdbyId with the username of the other record...

Comment: @eliot could you give me more details about your solution, which Apex class did you use to acomplish that, I have the same issue and I want to solve also with an apex action

Answer (score 0):

If anyone would still be looking for a solution for this, you don't necessarily have to create an invocable method for this. Instead you can make use of a record variable in your flow to which you assign a user id to the createdById in an assignment element. Then next use this record variable in the create element and it won't thrown errors.